# Recursive Function involving *html.Node to print all links in a HTML Doc

Tags: html, go, recursion, tree, nodes

I am trying to print all links in a HTML Doc using a function which accepts *html.Node as an argument. I am new to both Golang and the *html.Node datatype, I have never worked with them before.

```
func visit(links []string, n *html.Node) []string {
    if n == nil {
        return links
    }
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                links = append(links, a.Val)
            }
        }
    }
    if i == 0 {
        i++
        return visit(links, n.FirstChild)
    }
    return visit(links, n.NextSibling)
}
```

The aim of the if block which checks whether `i==0` is to ensure that `return visit(links, n.FirstChild)` only runs once (the first time) and `return visit(links, n.NextSibling)` runs on the following iterations. However, `links` never gets appended, and always returns an empty slice. I do not understand the error in my code.

The code works perfectly fine when using a for loop, but breaks when I try to use recursion.

```
for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        links = visit(links, c)
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the variable ```i``` in your question undefined?

Comment: I've declared the variable i outside the main/func block as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as in it takes the first child of the document, which is `html` element and then it takes its sibling element which is `nil` thus causing the function to end with empty slice of links.

To explain in detail:
Here's an example code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

var i int = 0

func visit(links []string, n *html.Node) []string {

    if n == nil {
        return links
    }

    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                links = append(links, a.Val)
            }
        }
    }

    if i == 0 {
        i++
        return visit(links, n.FirstChild)
    }

    return visit(links, n.NextSibling)
}

func main() {
    s := `<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li><a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul>`

    doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    links := visit([]string{}, doc)

    fmt.Println(links)
}
```

**1st call to `visit`,**
**Arguments:**
links = []
n = DocumentNode

In the first call, i=0, so it makes a recursive call to `visit` with the first child of the document node.

**2nd call to `visit`,**
**Arguments:**
links = []
n = ElementNode (n.Data = "html")

In the 2nd call, `n` is the `html` element node. Now a 3rd call to `visit` is made with the next sibling of the `html` element node.
And this is where the problem lies.
There is no sibling for `html` element node, so `n` will be `nil`.

**3rd call to `visit`,**
**Arguments:**
links = []
n = nil

So, now all the function 3 function calls that were called recursively will return and the flow of execution will go back to `main` and hence the slice `links` will remain empty.

Hope you understood.

The proper way to code this functionality is by the loop you shared in your question, like this,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func visit(links []string, n *html.Node) []string {

    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                links = append(links, a.Val)
            }
        }
    }

    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        links = visit(links, c)
    }

    return links
}

func main() {
    s := `<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li><a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul>`

    doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    links := visit([]string{}, doc)

    fmt.Println(links)
}
```

Here, the loop helps to recursively find the links by checking each and every HTML element's children. If one of the HTML elements have no siblings, then it would simply move on to its parent's next sibling element and check

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same problem for a while. According to the title the purpose of the question is how to replace `for` loop:

```golang
for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
    links = visit(links, c)
}
```

with recursive function. This `for` loop is a standard way to traverse the tree document included in [x/html](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html#pkg-overview) go package. Despite that @Ramaraja answer was accepted it doesn't contain a proper solution.

> Here, the loop helps to recursively find the links by checking each and every HTML element's children. If one of the HTML elements have no siblings, then it would simply move on to its parent's next sibling element and check

Based on this answer I tried this one:

```golang
if c := n.FirstChild; c != nil {
    links = visit(links, c)
} else if c.NextSibling != nil {
    links = visit(links, c.NextSibling)
}
```

The program triggers panic procedure. I'm not sure whether it is possible to avoid `for` loop at all.